# find the 4th Friday from Today's date with javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have been trying to make a quick reference sheet to use for work, and have been using this as a way to start trying to learn JavaScript. 
I've been stumped on how to display the date in dd/mm/yyyy for the 4th Friday (or any day) from the current date. If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to use setDate() for date addition. The following code should set you there:

```
<html>
<script>

// You might want to make a function out of this, btw.

dayWeWant = 5; // Friday 
today = new Date();

// So you want the fourth friday, eh?

// remember friday is 5 for getDay

if (today.getDay() < dayWeWant)  {  nextFri =  7 - (today.getDay() -  dayWeWant) }  // days remaining
else  { nextFri = dayWeWant - today.getDay(); }

// If today IS friday, you want 4 instead of 3. Of course,
// 3 can also be made into a "constant" variable, such as howManyWeeks or something

threeMore = nextFri + 3 * 7; // three more weeks

nextDate = new Date();

nextDate.setDate(today.getDate() + threeMore);

   alert (nextDate);





</script>
</html>
```

Code is intentionally well annotated and not as efficient it can be (and the constant numbers aren't nice - you can make them into parameters of some function) - but does the trick. From here, minor optimizations are possible (but not as readable, IOHO)

Hope This Helps,

TG

Comment: Fantastic, I'll start playing around with this. Thank you very much.